# How to parse JSON and put in HTML with infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, scroll

I want to read data from a json file and put in html. The json contains lots of data, so I want to use infinite scroll with it.

I have searched and found this example: https://codepen.io/anantanandgupta/pen/oLLgyN

```
var dataJSON = '[{"FeeType":"Domestic POS Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"Domestic PIN Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"International POS Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"International PIN Declined Fee ","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"ATM Domestic Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"One (1) no cost ATM withdrawal per deposit1, then $1.75 per transaction thereafter","FeeAmount":"1.75"},{"FeeType":"Domestic ATM Balance Inquiry Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per ATM Balance Inquiry","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"Domestic ATM Declined Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Withdrawal Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"3.00"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Balance Fee ","FeeDescription":"per ATM Balance Inquiry","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"OTC Withdrawal Fee","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"4.00"},{"FeeType":"International OTC Withdrawal Fee","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"4.00"},{"FeeType":"Currency Conversion Fee","FeeDescription":"3% of transaction amount","FeeAmount":"3.00%"},{"FeeType":"Card Replacement Fee","FeeDescription":"One (1) no cost replacement per calendar year or upon expiration; $5.00 per request thereafter for lost, stolen, and damaged cards.","FeeAmount":"5.00"},{"FeeType":" Expedited Card Replacement Fee ","FeeDescription":"$20.00 (per Card; an additional fee when a Card is reissued or replaced for any reason with requested expedited delivery)","FeeAmount":"20.00"},{"FeeType":"Check Refund Fee","FeeDescription":"$12.50 per refund check (When a refund check is issued for the remaining Card balance.","FeeAmount":"12.5"}]';

var dataObject = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
var listItemString = $('#listItem').html();

dataObject.forEach(buildNewList);

function buildNewList(item, index) {
  var listItem = $('<li>' + listItemString + '</li>');
  var listItemTitle = $('.title', listItem);
  listItemTitle.html(item.FeeType);
  var listItemAmount = $('.amount', listItem);
  listItemAmount.html(item.FeeAmount);
  var listItemDesc = $('.description', listItem);
  listItemDesc.html(item.FeeDescription);
  $('#dataList').append(listItem);
}
```

This is what I want for parse the json. But it does not include infinite scroll. So how to make it infinite scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event listener to the div in which you want to append the content (in your case `$('#dataList')` ), so that every time there is a scroll in the scrolled div the script checks if the bottom was reached.

```
// Detect when scrolled bottom
$('#dataList').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if ($('#dataList').scrollTop + $('#dataList').clientHeight >= $('#dataList').scrollHeight) {
    loadMore();
  }
});
//Loading more elements
function loadMore(){
  var dataJSON = '[{"FeeType":"Domestic POS Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"Domestic PIN Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"International POS Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"International PIN Declined Fee ","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"ATM Domestic Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"One (1) no cost ATM withdrawal per deposit1, then $1.75 per transaction thereafter","FeeAmount":"1.75"},{"FeeType":"Domestic ATM Balance Inquiry Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per ATM Balance Inquiry","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"Domestic ATM Declined Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Withdrawal Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"3.00"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Balance Fee ","FeeDescription":"per ATM Balance Inquiry","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"OTC Withdrawal Fee","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"4.00"},{"FeeType":"International OTC Withdrawal Fee","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"4.00"},{"FeeType":"Currency Conversion Fee","FeeDescription":"3% of transaction amount","FeeAmount":"3.00%"},{"FeeType":"Card Replacement Fee","FeeDescription":"One (1) no cost replacement per calendar year or upon expiration; $5.00 per request thereafter for lost, stolen, and damaged cards.","FeeAmount":"5.00"},{"FeeType":" Expedited Card Replacement Fee ","FeeDescription":"$20.00 (per Card; an additional fee when a Card is reissued or replaced for any reason with requested expedited delivery)","FeeAmount":"20.00"},{"FeeType":"Check Refund Fee","FeeDescription":"$12.50 per refund check (When a refund check is issued for the remaining Card balance.","FeeAmount":"12.5"}]';
  var dataObject = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
  var listItemString = $('#listItem').html();
  dataObject.forEach(buildNewList);
}
//Building an element
function buildNewList(item, index) {
  var listItem = $('<li>' + listItemString + '</li>');
  var listItemTitle = $('.title', listItem);
  listItemTitle.html(item.FeeType);
  var listItemAmount = $('.amount', listItem);
  listItemAmount.html(item.FeeAmount);
  var listItemDesc = $('.description', listItem);
  listItemDesc.html(item.FeeDescription);
  $('#dataList').append(listItem);
}
```